# what does "observation offset" and "predicted state mean" mean in pykalman standard filtercorrect module?

Tags: python, forecasting, kalman-filter

I am using a module `pykalman` in which I imported a function named `_filter_correct` in `pyklaman.standard` in order to correct my forecast data.

There are parameters in the function I do not understand even after trying to understand what is behind the function.

They say that:

- `observation_offset` is offset for observation at time `t`
- `predict_state_mean` which is the mean of state at time `t` given observations from `times[0...t-1]`.
- I understood the other parameters

I am forecasting by the way a univariate parameter(wind speed) for 7 days 6 hours ahead that I am concatenating!

Can you help me on the parameters of this function ?

Comment: Please put code around code tags. And the parameters should be described in the module's documentation so read that.

Comment: Can you be more rude please?I like rude people!
My question is that I don't understand what does observation offset mean in the explanations! There is no silly question just don't be arrogant!

Comment: How was I rude? I even said "please". Your English is very poor so the question was unclear to me and so I advised you to read the documentation, because that's where the parameters are described. Sorry for trying to help, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand `observation_offset` is really the measured noise mean. Kalman requires the noise to be zero mean Gaussian signal where an offset will break the prediction, library eliminated the offset by himself so asks for you to give value before. (But I don't think that necessary because I guess it calculates it anyway. Giving it before will just help for first iterations. But not sure because documentation is very poor. Another clue for hypothesis is that he assigned NULL as default value, so NULL should not be a problem)

For example, if your thermometer always gives the result as `real_temperature + 2 + zero_mean_gaussion_noise` then your `observation_offset` must be 2 to draw back noise to zero mean. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) you can find more detailed information.

I again assume (because couldn't find any predicted_state_mean so far through googling)`predicted_state_mean` as the name suggest the predicted result value. Kalman Filter has two phases; prediction and update. In prediction depending on your system dynamics, with the knowledge of your current state, you are predicting the next state.

Such as if you have a car at point 0 and moving with 5 units/seconds, then after 2 seconds your car will be at point 10. Kalman first predicts this information then compares the predicted and observed (your sensor data) results in the update state.